# Predicting emperical distribution (100 percentiles)

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models

I'm trying to come up with a distribution for how much each separate customer spends at a given time.

For most of these customers (~60%), I have enough datapoints (>1000) such that I can just generate the 100 percentiles based on those datapoints.

However, the other ~40% don't have enough datapoints to generate that distribution and was wondering if there's any model that is capable of predicting an emperical distribution for one of these customers. I know I could decrease the 1000 point threshold I've (somewhat arbitrarily) set but I'll still be left with a not insignificant amount of consumers without enough data to reliable estimate the percentiles.

I have >50 attributes about each customer that I can use as my predictor variables.

My current solution is to group the customers together based on these attributes and use all the customers' datapoints in each given group as their distribution.

Does anyone know of a better way of doing this? Ideally, I'd like to have some predictive model based off the customers attributes and any datapoints that they may or may not have!